# Cassandra Database replication to another instance

Tags: cassandra, replication

Is it possible to do Cassandra data replication into another server instance to run read only data operations on it? As we have explored SAN and it become more hardware expensive

Note: I am not allowed to copy data into file and therefore. It should be like mirroring of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cassandras internal replication for this. Use NetworkTopologyAwarePolicy and configure a second datacenter where data will be replicated to (can be lower than your production cluster). Then use this datacenter for your read-only workload and the other one for production.

Your application needs to be reconfigured to use LOCAL_QUORUM or another LOCAL consistency level so the second datacenter isn't used for requests.

This technique is uses for separating resource demanding analytic workloads from the rest for example.

Comment: You mean NetworkTopologyStategy ? 
If so, in NetworkTopologyStategy both data centers will be in sync and they have same set of data and able to serve independently? 
Among two, one can be a read only datacenter ?
Will this work for already created keyspaces ??

Comment: Both DC will be in sync and have the same data (correctly configured replication set on keyspace).  If you use LOCAL_* as consistencly level data will be served from the local DC your session points to. Strictly spoken the other DC can and will handle writes if you do them. "read-only-ness" must be ensured on application side.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I do not want to handle read only at application side. Do you aware of any open source/paid tools that will take care of read only replication?

Comment: If you can go with a different user: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra and a user with only `SELECT` permission.